# Inheritance: emulating non-virtual functions in Python

Tags: python, inheritance

I am new to Python, I am coming from C++ so I suspect my way of thinking is "tainted" by my preconceived notions. I will explain what I am trying to do and the issue I am facing, but please be aware that the code below is an "artificial" little example that reproduces my issue.

Say that at some point I have this scenario, where B only overrides A.plot_and_clear() as that is all I need from B:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def clear(self):
        print("clear A start")
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        print("clear A end")

    def plot(self):
        print("plot A start")
        print(str(self.x))
        print(str(self.y))
        print("plot A end")

    def plot_and_clear(self):
        print("plot & clear A start")
        self.plot()
        self.clear()
        print("plot & clear A end")


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        super().__init__(x, y)
        self.z = z

    def plot_and_clear(self):
        print("plot & clear B BAD start")
        super().plot_and_clear()
        print(str(self.z))
        self.z = 0
        print("plot & clear B BAD end")

def main():
    myObject = B(1, 2, 3)
    myObject.plot_and_clea()

main()
```

In this case the output is exactly what I would expect and goes as follows:

```
plot & clear B start
plot & clear A start
plot A start
1
2
plot A end
clear A start
clear A end
plot & clear A end
3
plot & clear B end
```

Later on I realize that I also need to override A.plot() with B.plot(), with all the rest remaining the same like so:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def clear(self):
        print("clear A start")
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        print("clear A end")

    def plot(self):
        print("plot A start")
        print(str(self.x))
        print(str(self.y))
        print("plot A end")

    def plot_and_clear(self):
        print("plot & clear A start")
        self.plot()
        self.clear()
        print("plot & clear A end")


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        super().__init__(x, y)
        self.z = z

    def plot(self):
        print("plot B start")
        super().plot()
        print(str(self.z))
        print("plot B end")

    def plot_and_clear(self):
        print("plot & clear B BAD start")
        super().plot_and_clear()
        print(str(self.z))
        self.z = 0
        print("plot & clear B BAD end")

def main():
    myObject = B(1, 2, 3)
    myObject.plot_and_clea()

main()
```

Now if we run the same main, the output is changed and erroneous and goes like this:

```
plot & clear B start
plot & clear A start
plot B start
plot A start
1
2
plot A end
3
plot B end
clear A start
clear A end
plot & clear A end
3
plot & clear B end
```

This is because now, the super().plot_and_clear() from B.plot_and_clear() calls B.plot() instead of A.plot(). The result of this is that by simply adding a function I have broken the previously good behavior of B.plot_and_clear(), which is puzzling to say the least.

I understand this is due to how the MRO works in python, which as it seems, is completely flipped compared to c++. Now wheter or not we know the exact reason why this happens I would still argue that the behavior is not desirable and there should be a way to prevent it, either by choosing some "safe" code structure or with some other language constructs.

Any idea of how I can either work "around" or "along" this aspect of the language?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the lengthy discussion in the comments above I think I have grasped the concept that in python all functions are virtual, and thus the described behavior is exactly what one would expect in C++ as well, when all base-class methods were virtual.

It would be however rather nice to have the option to declare base-class functions as non-virtual, so that one can control exactly how a base class method behaves when calling it from within another base-class method, regardless of what child classes do with their overrides.

So far I found two methods to somewhat reproduce that functionality or at least to partially control the behavior of the base-class:

Method 1): Call the base-class methods explicitly within other base-class methods when non-virtual behavior is needed:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def clear(self):
        print("clear A start")
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        print("clear A end")

    def plot(self):
        print("plot A start")
        print(str(self.x))
        print(str(self.y))
        print("plot A end")

    def plot_and_clear(self):
        print("plot & clear A start")
        A.plot(self)
        A.clear(self)
        print("plot & clear A end")


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        super().__init__(x, y)
        self.z = z

    def plot(self):
        print("plot B start")
        super().plot()
        print(str(self.z))
        print("plot B end")

    def plot_and_clear(self):
        print("plot & clear B BAD start")
        super().plot_and_clear()
        print(str(self.z))
        self.z = 0
        print("plot & clear B BAD end")

def main():
    myObject = B(1, 2, 3)
    myObject.plot_and_clea()

main()

# Output as desired despite the presence of overrides:

# plot & clear B start
# plot & clear A start
# plot A start
# 1
# 2
# plot A end
# clear A start
# clear A end
# plot & clear A end
# 3
# plot & clear B end
```

Method 2) Name-Mangle those functions that need to be non-virtual, and only use the name-mangled version internally:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def clear(self):
        print("clear A start")
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        print("clear A end")
    __clear = clear

    def plot(self):
        print("plot A start")
        print(str(self.x))
        print(str(self.y))
        print("plot A end")
    __plot = plot


    def plot_and_clear(self):
        print("plot & clear A start")
        self.__plot()
        self.__clear()
        print("plot & clear A end")


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        super().__init__(x, y)
        self.z = z

    def plot(self):
        print("plot B start")
        super().plot()
        print(str(self.z))
        print("plot B end")

    def plot_and_clear(self):
        print("plot & clear B BAD start")
        super().plot_and_clear()
        print(str(self.z))
        self.z = 0
        print("plot & clear B BAD end")

def main():
    myObject = B(1, 2, 3)
    myObject.plot_and_clea()

main()

# Output as desired despite the presence of overrides:

# plot & clear B start
# plot & clear A start
# plot A start
# 1
# 2
# plot A end
# clear A start
# clear A end
# plot & clear A end
# 3
# plot & clear B end
```

I hope this helps anyone that, like me, is having a tough time switching from a static to a dynamic language, even though probably at some point we should better embrace the language's core philosophy without trying to forcefully fit it to our old ways :)

Answer (score 1):

`__init__` should only be used to *initialize* an existing object. (Though the creation of the object and the call to `__init__` usually both happen inside the call to the type itself.)

Use dedicated class methods as alternative constructors (such as copy constructors or constructing an object from another object). For example,

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self, *, mass=0, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.mass_ = mass

    @classmethod
    def from_object(cls, obj, **kwargs):
        return cls(mass=obj.mass_, **kwargs)


class Vehicle(Object):
    def __init__(self, *, wheels=4, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.wheels_ = wheels
 
    @classmethod
    def from_vehicle(cls, vehicle, **kwargs):
        return cls(mass=vehicle.mass_, wheels=vehicle.wheels_, **kwargs)


o = Object(mass=100)
v1 = Vehicle.from_object(o)
v2 = Vehicle.from_vehicle(v2)

v3 = Vehicle.from_object(o, wheels=6)
v4 = Vehicle.from_vehicle(v3)
```

See https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ for why we use keyword arguments.

Even though `from_object` itself does not expect any additional keyword arguments, we accept keywords aruments that `cls` (which could be `Object` or any subclass of `Object`) might expect.

Note, too, that `Vehicle` itself doesn't have to define `from_object`; `Vehicle.from_object` will instead use `Object.from_object` to create a vehicle. That might sound strange, but the job of `Object.from_object` is *not* necessarily to create an `Object`, but to know how to "unpack" an instance of `Object` in order to create an instance of `cls`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it gave me some food for thought. Though I still miss some fundamental understanding on how to deal with inheritance in certain conditions. I completely edited my initial post with a new, more generic code example which hopefully should highlight my issue better

Comment: Both use the method resolution order (MRO) to determine whose `post` method to call. `self.post()` uses the *first* method found, starting with the type of `self` itself. `super().post_and_clear` *skips* the type of `self` itself, then looks for the *next* class that provides a `post_and_clear` method.

Comment: Indeed that was also my understanding, but how to handle it in a predictable and safe way? say that in class B I had only implemented method plot_and_clear_bad(), and no clear() nor plot() as perhaps that was all I needed at the time. That would have behaved exactly like plot_and_clear_good() and I would have been happy. Then later on I realize that I need to override the B.plot() method too for whatever reason. That would change the behavior of my B.plot_and_clear_bad() that was working fine just before. This seems absurd to me...

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If you call `B().plot_and_clear_bad()` and `B.plot()` is defined, `A.plot_and_clear` will still call `B.plot()` not `A.plot()`. It's the *runtime* type of `self` that matters, not the particular method calling `self.plot`. (If you are expecting `A.plot_and_clear()` to always call `A.plot`, regardless of the type of `self`, then *that's* your problem.)

Comment: Hello, once again I updated my question with a clearer example illustrating the problem. Does this help? Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear why you think this is broken. If `B` overrides `A.plot`, why do you *not* want `B.plot` to be called?

Comment: Well why would anyone want the behavior of their current functions randomly modified when they add another override without touching anything else in the code. One would have to thoroughly check all classes in the inheritance tree every time they write any function. By mistake one might end up overriding a method a number of levels of inheritance below their class by casually choosing the same method name and go from one perfectly working class to a completely broken one. What am I missing here?

Comment: Nothing was randomly modified. You defined `B.plot`, and you should be aware that `B.plot_and_clear` calls `B.plot` (via `A.plot_and_clear`). The fact that `A.plot` was called before is the result of `B.plot` not being explicitly defined, not by the fact that it was being calle from inside `A.plot_and_clear`.

Comment: And yes, inheritance involves rather a lot of due diligence and documentation to properly understand how it works. It's one reason why many people recommend composition over inheritance where possible.

Comment: Allright, I think I am beginning to understand: I think the issue is that in python all functions are virtual (I kind-of knew it but it didn't sink in until now). This is the difference with C++ that I was missing, as what I was trying to achieve here was the equivalent of redefining in B some non-virtual methods of A. How will I mold my coding style around this notion I am not yet sure though. I am all for runtime polymorphism but I am not used to only having that option...